# How to backtest Strategy in pine script more than a year?

Tags: pine-script

How to backtest Strategy in pine script more than a year?

I have strategy for nifty in 5 mins chart. when I am running it, it shows result only for last 100 days.. previous data not visible in the chart.

but, if I keep chart time frame more than 5 mins data (candles) come more than that, more time frame more dates back shows.. but my strategy works in 5 mins. I would like to test it for last two / five years.. How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The depth of history is measured in bars—not time. The quantity of bars on charts varies with your type of account. See [this PineCoders FAQ entry](https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#why-cant-i-backtest-deeper-into-history) for more information.

> **Disclosure**: the link in this answer points to a PineCoders FAQ entry.
> I am a member of the PineCoders community and I most probably wrote that FAQ entry. PineCoders is a TradingView-supported group of volunteer Pine coders and PineCoders' website is strictly educational. Neither TradingView nor PineCoders benefits financially from sending traffic to pinecoders.com, and the site contains no affiliate/referral links.